# Start first Activity with onActivityResult

Tags: android, eclipse, android-intent, set

I want open two other Activities and then I want to play a selected song from the Activity C in Activity A.on Activity **A** I open an Activity **B** and there I open an Activity **C**. 
I want to play a **selected** Song in Activity **C**.

But I don't get it. Whats wrong? 
Thanks a lot, Vinzenz :)

---

This is ActivityA:

```
LinearLayoutBrowse.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BrowseActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(i, 100); 

            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
              @Override
              public void run() {
                  mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
              }
            }, 300);

        }
    });

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,
                                 int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(resultCode == 100){
         currentSongIndex = data.getExtras().getInt("songIndex");

         //drawerclose


         // play selected song
         playSong(currentSongIndex);

    }

}
```

---

This is ActivityB:

```
      LinearLayoutTitel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            myViewFlipper.showPrevious();
            Intent i = new Intent(BrowseActivity.this, AllSongs.class);
            startActivityForResult(i,  100);

        }
    });


}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // this is the data that comes back from Activity C when Activity C calls finish()

    // set the data as the result
    setResult(???);

    // then you can finish
    finish();
}
```

---

This is ActivityC:

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // getting listitem index
            int songIndex = position;

            // Starting new intent
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    MainActivity.class);


            // Sending songIndex to BrowseActivity
            in.putExtra("songIndex", songIndex);

            setResult(100, in);
            // Closing PlayListView
            finish();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your third `Activity`, the `Intent` constructor should be empty. Instead of

```
Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
```

it should be

```
Intent in = new Intent();
```

otherwise, you are creating a new instance of `MainActivity` and it will call its `onCreate()`.